# Redirect is only possible to ip address by dns hosting settings

Tags: redirect, web, dns, ip, digital-ocean

I needed to bind hosting/vps IP to domain on domain provider side. Tutorials say I need to copy those lines and enter on domain provider website somewhere.

```
ns1.digitalocean.com.
ns2.digitalocean.com.
ns3.digitalocean.com.
```

I open my domain provider settings. There are default NS servers

```
nsb4.srv53.com nsb3.srv53.com .....
```

Which are told not be touched and that all settings must be done on other website here https://dnshosting.org/

At this website opposite to my domain in my account there only the following options

1. Default parking page(wrong for sure)
2. Redirect through frames (not our case)
3. Custom parking page(wrong also)
4. Switch off redirect(><)
5. Direct redirect (what I need)

But redirect is only possible to ip address, not `ns2.digitalocean.com.`, which means that ip address will be shown in url, not domain - so I guess that's all wrong.

Help, please. Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Can we see that tutorial?

Comment: @DusanBajic https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars

Comment: Did you register your domain name at `dnshosting.org`?

Comment: @DusanBajic no, I registered domain with local dns provider imena.ua, which redirect to dnshosting.org for managing domain purposes

Comment: To quote the tutorial: "...then you can continue with changing the nameservers with your registrar.". So, if you will be using DigitalOcean nameservers, go to imena.ua and enter digitalocean nameservers

Comment: @DusanBajic  I tried deleting default nameservers,but after dns updated, it just coudn't find my domain address 404

Comment: @DusanBaijic there were also some additional setup called Glue Records, but it didn't work for me either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145466/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-vinand).